# How can I get the names of days of week in JodaTime

Tags: java, datetime, arraylist, jodatime, days

I've a problem to calculate an entire name list of days of week, using JodaTime.
Pratically, I would like to see a similar output based on Locale:

```
1 day: Sunday 
2 day: Monday 
3 day: Tuesday 
4 day: Wednesday 
5 day: Thursday 
6 day: Friday 
7 day: Saturday
```

How can I do? I'm new in JodaTime libraries...

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From Joda-Time [userguide](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html):

> For instance, the direct way to get the day of week for a particular DateTime, involves calling the method

```
int iDoW = dt.getDayOfWeek();

where iDoW can take the values (from class DateTimeConstants).

public static final int MONDAY = 1;
public static final int TUESDAY = 2;
public static final int WEDNESDAY = 3;
public static final int THURSDAY = 4;
public static final int FRIDAY = 5;
public static final int SATURDAY = 6;
public static final int SUNDAY = 7;


...
 Localized versions of these methods are also available, thus
  DateTime.Property pDoW = dt.dayOfWeek();
  String strTF = pDoW.getAsText(Locale.FRENCH); // returns "Lundi", etc.
```

**EDIT**
If using Default Locale

```
DateTime.Property pDoW = dt.dayOfWeek();
String strTF = pDoW.getAsText(Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: Thanks!! :) last question: how can I work with Locale.getDefault()? could be changed values from class DateTimeConstants?

Answer (score 23):

Looks like a job for [DateTimeFormat](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

I would start with

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
 DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE"); // use 'E' for short abbreviation (Mon, Tues, etc)
 String strEnglish = fmt.print(dt);
 String strFrench = fmt.withLocale(Locale.FRENCH).print(dt);
 String strWhereverUR = fmt.withLocale(Locale.getDefault()).print(dt);
```

and go from there

Comment: Thanks man! :) good solution...but, can I work with Locale.getdefault()? I wouldn't manage every Locale...

Comment: Actually "E" pattern only prints "Fri". For "Friday" use "EEEE".